# Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS does not work correctly

Tags: android, android-download-manager

One of my clients feedbacked me with that the files downloaded via my app aren't  placed in the Downloads folder. Instead of Downloads directory, they are collected in another custom directory similar to my application package name like 'v2MyApp' which I have never mentioned in my java code. I am using `setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(f1,Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,fileName);` and trying to force my files to be save in Downloads directory with Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS but why this could happen. I have no idea. Any suggestion will be great. Or any solution to save them ensure in "Downloads" directory.

Thnx.

BTW issue happens on only this client no emulator or any other device made it.

Download flow:

```
if (isOnline()) {
                                        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.some_vw);
                                        wv.loadUrl("some.url/");

                                        wv.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                                                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                                                request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(Activity.this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,fileName);
                                                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                                                dm.enqueue(request);
                                            }

                                        });}
```

Comment: please share the code where your download flow is, may be you are setting wrong path and not using this path

Comment: I added it check the below

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you meant to use [`setDestinationInExternalPublicDir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

> Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the public external storage directory (as returned by `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String)`).

as opposed to `setDestinationInExternalFilesDir`

> Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the application's external files directory (as returned by `getExternalFilesDir(String)`).